# Inability to call or text with Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

My Samsung Galaxy S3 has this annoying habit that, whenever I try to do something like connect to a network, or open Candy Crush, after 20 seconds my phone will turn off, and on, and then keep turning off and on, the timing at which it turns off after turning on is variable: sometimes I have the option to enter my PIN, most of the time not.

Up until this point I solved it by plugging it in, and stop attempting to do anything  with this phone that I cannot do on my old Nokia. The problem this time, is that my phone has entered a state of isolation: I cannot text, or receive texts, cannot call and the symbol which normally shows how good my connection is to my network has been replaced by a stop sign. How do I get rid of this?

Also, my battery occasionally drains: from full to 0 in under 2 minutes.

Placing my SIM into a different phone allowed me to text and call, so its nothing to do with that.

Comment: You could try booting into [safe-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info) and see if the problem persists (you won't have your user-apps available there, but should be able to do some testing). If it works fine there, it's most likely a software issue – if not, it's a case for service. Option 2: backup everything and do a [factory-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info). Same stuff: either the problem is gone, or you've got to send the device for service.

Answer (score 0):

Take a backup of your phone and do a hard reset.

Steps for a hard Reset

1. Turn the phone off.
2. Press and hold VOLUME UP and Home(center) button Press Power until
   the phone vibrate Wait until you see the Android   logo then release
   all the buttons
3. Select Wipe data/Factory reset with VOLUME DOWN, press Power (right
       hand-side) Select YES -- delete all user data with VOLUME DOWN and
       then press Power After format,    press Power again to reboot phone.
       (select reboot system now)

[Source](http://www.hard-reset.com/samsung-galaxy-s3-hard-reset.html)